# Building an Active Record scope of 'editor approved' versions of user-generated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, paper-trail-gem, user-generated-content

I run a site similar to StackOverflow where users can publish content (Posts). There also is a frontpage showcasing featured Posts picked by our editors.

I want to allow our users to edit their Posts anytime, while still making sure nothing appears on our frontpage without it first being reviewed by our editors.

To solve this, I figured we could implement a versioning system like [`paper_trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) and store the current `version_id` whenever we feature a Post. This way we can simply fetch the editor-reviewed content on the frontpage, while still showing the most recent version on less critical parts of the site such as the user's profile. Our editors can periodically review any changes and approve those.

I'm wondering what the cleanest approach is that allows me to select reviewed versions in some controllers and the latest versions in others while keeping a shared interface and minimally duplicated code.

---

**The ideal solution would involve a `reviewed` scope so I could simply do `Post.reviewed` and get back the reviewed versions, and `Post.all` to get the latest versions.**

I'm not sure how to go about this though, as getting the reviewed version requires de-serializing the object PaperTrail stores (`version.reify`) and that doesn't seem possible within a scope.

#### I could use a class method instead like this:

`def self.reviewed
 all.map do |post|
    Version.find(post.version_id).reify
  end.compact! || Post.none
end`

However, this is less than ideal as it's not a real scope and thus not chainable, etc.

#### Alternatively I could use a Post instance method like:

`def reviewed_version
  Version.find(version_id).reify
end`

This works in theory, but this means I now have to call this method all over my views, whereas it's the responsibility of the controller to fetch the right data. Let's say I have a `render collection: @posts` on both the frontpage and user profile, how does my `_post.html.erb` partial know whether to call `reviewed_version` or not.

---

I'm not tied to PaperTrail, but it has a lot of niceties I prefer not having to duplicate. I'm open to exploring other directions if PaperTrail proves too inflexible however.

FWIW, I have looked at [Draftsman](https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman) as well, but it considers the 'draft' as the exception (i.e. in most cases you wouldn't show the draft), whereas in my case I want to show the most recent version on most pages, except for a particular few like the frontpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds over complicated for doing something that is quite simple by itself:

- you have a `Post` model, which contains common attributes (like author and creation date)
- `Post has_many :revisions`
- a `Revision` has a `reviewed` boolean attribute

If you want to find the last reviewed revision for a `Post`, you can have:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

  delegate :content, to: :current_revision # you can even have those to transparently delegate

  def current_revision
    @current_revision ||= revisions.where( reviewed: true ).order( "created_at desc" ).first
  end
end
```

if you want to retrieve only `Post`s which have reviewed revisions:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

  scope :reviewed, ->{ group( 'posts.id' ) ).having( 'count(revisions.id) > 0' ).joins( :revisions ).where( "revisions.reviewed = ?", true ) }
end
```

This is how I would have done it, let people more familiar with `paper_trail` tell you about its way :)

**EDIT**

As discussed in comments, a decorator may also help to differentiate the revision and delegate methods to it, while still being able to pass an activerecord relation. Which give something in that way:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

  scope :reviewed, ->{ group( 'posts.id' ) ).having( 'count(revisions.id) > 0' ).joins( :revisions ).where( "revisions.reviewed = ?", true ) }

  def reviewed_revision
    @reviewed_revision ||= revisions.where( reviewed: true ).order( "created_at desc" ).first
  end

  def latest_revision
    @latest_revision ||= revisions.order( "created_at desc" ).first
  end
end

class PostDecorator
  attr_reader :post, :revision
  delegate :content, :updated_at, to: :revision

  def self.items( scope, revision_method )
    revision_method = :reviewed_revision unless %i[ reviewed_revision latest_revision ].include?( revision_method )

    scope.map do |post|
      PostDecorator.new( post, post.send( revision_method ) )
    end
  end

  def initalize( post, revision )
    @post, @revision = post, revision
  end

  def method_missing( action_name, *args, &block )
    post.send( action_name, *args, &block )
  end
end

# view
#
# <% PostDecorator.items( Post.reviewed.limit(10), :reviewed_revision ).each do |post| %>
# <p><%= post.author.name %></p>
# <p><%= simple_format post.content %></p>
# <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. That does indeed simplify things, but it still requires calling 'current_revision' throughout my views as the 'reviewed' scope merely filters Posts with a revision, rather than actually returning the right revisions. (As mentioned in the question I want all filtering/selection taken care of when doing Post.reviewed so further down the stack I can treat it the same as whatever Post.all returns.)

Comment: That's why I mentioned the `delegate` method ;) It allows you to use methods from `Revision` on `Post`, as if the method was directly on it. In my example, you can use `post.content`, it will be the same as `post.current_revision.content`. As for filtering, I guess most filtered attributes are on `Post`, and not `Revision`?

Comment: Right, but sometimes I need the `current_revision` (`reviewed: true`) while other times I need the latest revision regardless of whether it's been reviewed or not. So I only want that delegation to happen when these posts were scoped with `.reviewed` – I'm starting to think that scopes aren't the right approach though and am currently looking into decorators.

Comment: Decorators are usually not very usable to deal with AR collections, but it would totally help for a specific record. They would be helpful to delegate different sets of methods to a record - depending on whether it's a reviewed one or not - and could be use in place of Post in views. So scope (for collections) + decorators (for instances) should do the trick.

Comment: I was able to decorate a collection of Posts with the Draper gem. It's indeed not ideal as it undoes some of the niceties of vanilla ActiveRecord collections, but so far it's the closed I've come to my intended solution.

Comment: I was thinking about it too :) I thought "actually, we could use the power of AR and pass it to a decorator". Here what I had : https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/88f5b4c45d590333e58705bff64cbdf1

Comment: That's perfect! Mind adding that to your answer? (probably best to paste the code here). I'll then mark it as accepted.